# Scrollbar not visible in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, dojo

I am trying to use iframe with src pointing to a website made in dojo framework. My URL is on different server and and my iframe is on different server. I am just using URL to load URL's content inside iframe. But I can't see the scrollbar with iframe although the page content is more than iframe.

My code is:

```
<div style="overflow:visible; width: 100%;">
    <iframe src="http://172.27.135.85:2040/feg/ngfeeui/public/" width="80%" height="400px" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" style="overflow: auto;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Can someone help me if this issue is due to some javascript or css used in dojo framework? If needed I can post the full code of URL also, what I am able to see in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is in an answer, I don't have the points to comment yet.  Does your browser support iframes?  Check here:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_scrolling