# Scrollbar not visible on JSP when showing extended information on bottom of page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, scrollbar

I am developing in an older apploication using JSP and Frames for HTML. I call my JSP by clicking a link in a toolbar. On the called page I have some information and everything is working fine. However, I also have some hidden information which is shown by clicking a button on the page and thereby calling a JavaScript function for it to be shown. When calling this function, however, the information is 'presented' at the bottom 'outside' of the page and no scroll bar is visible. If I then click the link in my toolbar to 'reload' the page there is a scrollbar visible. This, I believe, is because I have the following JavaScript in the body onLoad=document.body.scrollTop=document.forms[0].scrollPos.value;

I have tried to reload the JSP inside my JavaScript with the window.location.reload(); & parent.location.reload(); but this causes a warning to be shown (if you are performing transactions make sure blablabla).

This is how I call my JSP from the menu:

```
<frameset border="0" cols="100%" rows="100%">
<frame name="eoPartInfoHeader" src="/glopps/processEoPartInfo.do?method=initializeForm" noresize="noresize">
</frameset>
```

This is body on called JSP:

```
<body onLoad="setTitle('<bean:message key="title.eoPartInfo"/>');document.forms[0].jump.selectedIndex=0;setFocus();document.body.scrollTop=document.forms[0].scrollPos.value;">
```

Error should be kind of similar to these questions:

[Scrollbar not visible in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172049/scrollbar-not-visible-in-iframe)

[scrollbar in jsp with window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654773/scrollbar-in-jsp-with-window-open)

Comment: What's if you resize your browser to very little height. Do you get scrollbars? What happens, if you enter the frame url direct in your browser?

Comment: ah, very intereseting. If I change the size of my browser I won't get any scrollbar. If I open the frame url directly in browser though, I _will_ get a scrollbar.

The CSS I'm using for body looks like th following:
    body { background-color: rgb(221,222,241); margin: 0px 14px; color: black; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;}

I've tried to add overflow: auto to the CSS fo body but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

If anyone ever reads this here's how I solved it. Turns out we had a JavaScript function in another JSP which looks like this:

```
function setScrollbar() {   
if(document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight){
    document.body.scroll="yes";
}   
else{
    document.body.scroll="no";
}       
}
```

Then that function is justed called on body load:

```
<body onLoad=setScrollbar();">
```